# Simple Question On Relationship Between Cubes And Squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

I'm new to this number theory business, not to mention terribly naive.  I wonder whether someone could explain the technique (assuming there is one) to show whether the expression

$12C - 3$

(where $C$ is any cube number greater than $1$) can ever be a square number.

In particular, I'm looking for a square number congruent to $3 \mod 6$, but I'll settle for just any square number for now.  A simple search of the first few hundred cube numbers turned up nothing (apart from the trivial $C = 1$)

Sorry if this question has you mathematicians rolling your eyes.

Thank you so much for your help.  By the way, if anyone can suggest a really gentle introduction to number theory, would you mind recommending a book to me?  Thanks.

Regards,

Mike.

Comment: Let $a,b$ be natural numbers so that $12a^3-3=b^2$, and then manipulate this equation to try to find a solution. Or, for your second question, try to find $n\in\Bbb{N}$ so that $n^2\equiv 3 \mod 6$.

Comment: @KSmarts: That's just restating the question, isn't it? Writing $12a^3-3=b^2$ is a more conventional _wording_ of the problem than the OP's, but doesn't seem to represent any actual progress in solving it.

Comment: For the square being $3 \pmod 6$, this happens if and only if the _root_ of the square is itself $3\pmod 6$, so in that case the equation is $12a^3-3=(6c+3)^2$ -- which reduces to $a^3=3c^2+3c+1$.

Comment: Just a little comment: $12C-3$ is always congruent to $3$ $\mod 6$ for an integer $C$, since $12C-3 = 6(2C-1) +3$.

Comment: @Henning Malkolm And this means that $a^3+c^3 = (c+1)^3$ which is impossible for $c>0$. So $C=1$ is the only solution.

Comment: @Litho: That seems to close the case. You should write that up as an answer.

Comment: You are looking for integer solutions to $y^2 = 12 x^3 - 3$. Although the factor $12$ puts this strictly speaking out of the elliptic curve definition, most of the work on those applies. In particular, Siegel's theorem says there will be only a finite number of integer solutions. However, in general, elliptic curves are hard, and if there is a general method to find all the solutions, it is probably way to tough to explain here. For this particular equation, Henning's reasoning above shows there are no other solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  It gives me something to look up.  Elliptical equations look very frightening, especially to a non-mathematician!

Answer (score 7):

First of all, $12C-3 = 6(2C-1)+3$, so $12C-3 \equiv 3 \pmod 6$ for any integer $C$. As Henning Makholm wrote, if a square is $3 \pmod 6$, then the root of the square is also $3 \pmod 6$, so if $12a^3-3 = k^2$, then $k = 6c+3$ for an integer $c$, and the relation can rewritten as
$$
12a^3-3 = (6c+3)^2,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
a^3 = 3c^2+3c+1
$$
or 
$$
a^3+c^3 = (c+1)^3.
$$
This is impossible for $c>0$ (it's a particular case of Fermat's Last Theorem for $n=3$; this case has been proven by Leonhard Euler), so $C=1$ is the only solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks to Litho and Henning for your very instructive replies. I was actually approaching it from the opposite direction. I started from the difference of two cubes and ended up with the expression given in my question. If it's possible to prove in some other way that it cannot be a square number, it would (perhaps) prove Fermat's Last Theorem for n = 3. I've been looking at prime number decomposition, but haven't got anywhere, which doesn't say much because it's not something I'm familiar with. Thanks so much.

Answer (score -3):

$1 ^ 3 + 2 ^ 3 = 3 ^ 2$. Likewise $1 ^ 3 + 2 ^ 3 + 3 ^ 3 = 6 ^ 2$. $1+2= 3$ and $1+2+3 = 6$. Like wise sum of cubes of first $4$ number is square of $10$ ($1+2+3+4$). How is it? You can check up to any number of your choice and prove whether I am right or wrong.